# Make a scrolling panel in python (WX python)

Tags: python, wxpython

So I already have a nice wx.Frame built. It is totally functional. I wish to make it a scrollable area. I have looked on the wx python API and it said that the following code should do it:

```
    self.panel = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(parent = self, id = -1)
    self.panel.SetupScrolling()


    self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
    self.panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(self.Red, self.Blue, self.Green))
    self.box = wx.FlexGridSizer(fileList.__len__(), 5, 5,5)
    self.FileObjects = []
    self.BatchProblemFileObjects = []
```

This creates scroll bars, but only AFTER I resize the window and only if there is a need for it. Is there anyway to make it so that I do not have to resize the window to make the scroll bars appear?

Thanks for your help.

(Running on python 2.7)

Comment: Have you tried `self.Layout()` (or, if that doesn't work, `self.panel.Layout()`)? It forces a bunch of things like size recalculations and redraws. It's the first thing I try when I have any wxPython layout problems.

Comment: I finally got to my dev machine and ried your code. I see the scrollbar both with any without the `Layout()` call I suggest above. Could you explain your problem in greater detail?

Comment: Hope the edit helped. Thanks acattle

Comment: Do you just want to scrollbars to be visible (but greyed out) or do you want your panel to be a default size?

Comment: I would rather the panel be a default size and if the content is too big for it the scroll bars should appear.

Comment: In my experience, that's exactly what `wx.lib.ScrolledPanel` does. Maybe try moving "set up scrolling" to the end of the init? Maybe also add `self.SetAutoLayout(True)`?

Comment: Why do you set `self.panel` twice? The first time as `wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel` on line 1 then later as a `wx.Panel` on line 5.