# Creating a scrolling panel in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Level: Beginner

I recently started to programme a GUI application with wxPython. I am facing a problem in creating a scrollable panel. I already have a `wx.Frame` which is working fine. There are 2 panels in my gui. (Please neglect the panel-3 for this moment) I would like to make my panel-2 scrollable so that it can contain more elements. The basic structure my GUI is as below:

[image: GUI demo]

I have tried using the `wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel()` in my code but the scroll bar is not appearing for some reason. My code is as below:

```
panel2 = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(self,-1, size=(600,400), pos=(0,28), style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
panel2.SetupScrolling()
button1 = wx.Button(panel2,label="Button 1",pos=(0,50),size=(50,50))
button2 = wx.Button(panel2,label="Button 2",pos=(0,100), size=(50,50))
button3 = wx.Button(panel2,label="Button 3",pos=(0,150),size=(50,50))
button4 = wx.Button(panel2,label="Button 4",pos=(0,200), size=(50,50))
button5 = wx.Button(panel2,label="Button 5",pos=(0,250),size=(50,50))
button6 = wx.Button(panel2,label="Button 6",pos=(0,300), size=(50,50))
button7 = wx.Button(panel2,label="Button 7",pos=(0,350), size=(50,50))
button8 = wx.Button(panel2,label="Button 8",pos=(0,400), size=(50,50))
```

Currently when I execute my code I get panel-2 with 7 buttons only instead of 8. I was hoping that the 8th button would create the scroll bar as it will not fit in the panel-2's dimensions.
Can anyone suggest what could be a possible solution to my problem or am I missing something?

Thank you for your time &
PS: There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110842/make-a-scrolling-panel-in-python-wx-python) but is not answered.

The complete code can be found here below:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel

    class GUI(wx.Frame):

        def __init__(self,parent,id,title):
            #First retrieve the screen size of the device
            screenSize = wx.DisplaySize()
            screenWidth = screenSize[0]
            screenHeight = screenSize[1]

            #Create a frame
            wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,title,size=screenSize, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER)

            panel1 = wx.Panel(self,size=(screenWidth,28), pos=(0,0), style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
            panel1.SetBackgroundColour('#FDDF99')
            panel2 = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(self,-1, size=(screenWidth,400), pos=(0,28), style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
            panel2.SetupScrolling()
            panel2.SetBackgroundColour('#FFFFFF')
            button1 = wx.Button(panel2,label="Button 1",pos=(0,50),size=(50,50))
            button2 = wx.Button(panel2,label="Button 2",pos=(0,100), size=(50,50))
            button3 = wx.Button(panel2,label="Button 3",pos=(0,150),size=(50,50))
            button4 = wx.Button(panel2,label="Button 4",pos=(0,200), size=(50,50))
            button5 = wx.Button(panel2,label="Button 5",pos=(0,250),size=(50,50))
            button6 = wx.Button(panel2,label="Button 6",pos=(0,300), size=(50,50))
            button7 = wx.Button(panel2,label="Button 7",pos=(0,350), size=(50,50))
            button8 = wx.Button(panel2,label="Button 8",pos=(0,400), size=(50,50))


    if __name__=='__main__':
        app = wx.App()
        frame = GUI(parent=None, id=-1, title="Test")
        frame.Show()
        app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add a sizer into the scrolled panel to contain all the buttons.
These code should work:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel

class GUI(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id,title):
        #First retrieve the screen size of the device
        screenSize = wx.DisplaySize()
        screenWidth = screenSize[0]
        screenHeight = screenSize[1]
    
        #Create a frame
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,title,size=screenSize, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER)

        panel1 = wx.Panel(self,size=(screenWidth,28), pos=(0,0), style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
        panel1.SetBackgroundColour('#FDDF99')
        panel2 = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(self,-1, size=(screenWidth,400), pos=(0,28), style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
        panel2.SetupScrolling()
        panel2.SetBackgroundColour('#FFFFFF')


        button1 = wx.Button(panel2,label="Button 1",pos=(0,50),size=(50,50))
        button2 = wx.Button(panel2,label="Button 2",pos=(0,100), size=(50,50))
        button3 = wx.Button(panel2,label="Button 3",pos=(0,150),size=(50,50))
        button4 = wx.Button(panel2,label="Button 4",pos=(0,200), size=(50,50))
        button5 = wx.Button(panel2,label="Button 5",pos=(0,250),size=(50,50))
        button6 = wx.Button(panel2,label="Button 6",pos=(0,300), size=(50,50))
        button7 = wx.Button(panel2,label="Button 7",pos=(0,350), size=(50,50))
        button8 = wx.Button(panel2,label="Button 8",pos=(0,400), size=(50,50))



        bSizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )
        bSizer.Add( button1, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )
        bSizer.Add( button2, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )
        bSizer.Add( button3, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )
        bSizer.Add( button4, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )
        bSizer.Add( button5, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )
        bSizer.Add( button6, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )
        bSizer.Add( button7, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )
        bSizer.Add( button8, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )
        panel2.SetSizer( bSizer )

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = GUI(parent=None, id=-1, title="Test")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Perfect! I was trying to do the same using boxer, but it was not working for me. Thank a lot. :)

Comment: To elaborate (because @user3239580 beat me to it :) ) the reason you were not getting scroll bars is because your scrolled panel was never being resized to the window size.  That's what the sizer does.